# Proving Kramers-Kronig relationships from Fourier sine / cosine transform

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a real function $A(t)$,  the Fourier-sine and –cosine transforms are defined as

$$ A’(\omega) = \omega \int_0^{\infty}A(\tau) sin(\omega \tau) \mathrm{d}\tau $$
$$  A’’(\omega) = \omega \int_0^{\infty}A(\tau) cos(\omega \tau) \mathrm{d}\tau $$
By inversion-transforming one could also write
$$ A(t) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\infty}  \frac{ A’(\omega) }{\omega} sin(\omega t) \mathrm{d}\omega  $$
$$  A(t) =\frac{2}{\pi}   \int_0^{\infty}   \frac{ A’’(\omega) }{\omega } cos(\omega t) \mathrm{d}\omega $$
One can then appreciate that the knowedge of, say, $A’$, results in the knowledge of $A’’$. 
As this is also implied by the Kramer-Kronig relationship, I thought they could be derived via this route. 
So I try to express $A’$ using $A’’$ by a substitution (the fourth equation above in the first), and end up with
$$  A’(\omega) =\frac{2 \omega}{\pi}   \int_0^{\infty}  \int_0^{\infty}     \frac{ A’’(s) }{s} cos(s \tau) sin (\omega \tau) \mathrm{d} s \mathrm{d}\tau $$
And now I am unsure on how to proceed to get to Kramer-Kronig
$$ A’(\omega) =\frac{2}{\pi}   \int_0^{\infty}   \frac{s  A’’(s) }{s^2 - \omega^2 } \mathrm{d}s $$
 Should integrate one out, but the integral
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} cos(ax) sin(ax) \mathrm{d}x $$ is not taking me far.
Any suggestion, most appreciated